# Why is new IE popup window initially empty but filled after F5 (refresh)?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a web app which opens a new browser window (using window.open) when a link is clicked. The very first time the window is opened it remains empty. The call is to a report generator and this returns a PDF document.

If the link is clicked a second time or if the new window is refreshed then the correct content is displayed.

This is only happening in IE (I'm using IE8) on the production server but not on the test server.

I have used HttpAnalyser to check the traffic and I cannot spot any differences between the different scenarios.

Here is the script

```
var url = "http://myserver/webapps/birt/run?__title=MMS Report&__report=Report/" + report + "&__lc=en&__format=pdf&__runtime=prod&";
var chk = document.getElementById('chkPageBreak');
if(chk && chk.checked) url += "PageBreak=true&";
if(params) {
    params = params.replace('%MMSFAIRID%', '25');
    params = params.replace('%LANGUAGE%', 'en');
}
url += params;
birturl = url;
birtwin = window.open(url,'MMSBIRT', 'menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=1,scrollbars=1');
```

Why might this be happening? What can I do to prevent it?

Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the request

```
GET /webapps/birt/run
    ?__title=MMS%20Report
    &__report=Report/emosBuildStaffGrouped.rptdesign
    &__lc=en
    &__format=pdf
    &__runtime=prod
    &MmsFairId=25
    &Language=en
    &Inland=false
```

Here is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 12:30:31 GMT
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="emosBuildStaffGrouped.pdf"
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx:-1; Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Language: de-DE
```

What just caught my eye is the strange Expires value. 1994?!? no idea where that is coming from. When I refresh the page then no Set-Cookie and no Expires is received....

Comment: Are you sure the mime type and the size of the PDF document are correctly sent from the production server ?

Comment: I don't think it's valid to have an unescaped space in your URL.

Comment: @dystroy thanks. You're probably right about the space. I'll correct it. However, it seems the browser does the right thing anyhow. See my update.